# amazon s3 aws url path subdirectories buckets

Tags: html, url, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I have a small blog on s3 on amazon aws. I have my domain name linking to it and I have set it up according to the [standard tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).

The tutorial was helpful enough to explain that i need two buckets such that http://www.koaning.com as well as http://koaning.com sucesfully link to my blog. When you click a link on my blog you will be linked to the correct page and the url that you see on top of the browser remains the same. The problem though is that I cannot seem to link subdirectories of the bucket while using my domain name.

**Working Link**

- http://koaning.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/html/consolelog.html

**Nonworking Equivalents**

- http://koaning.com/html/consolelog.html
- http://www.koaning.com/html/consolelog.html

Why is it not linking correctly? What step have I missed? Do I need to set something extra up to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either haven't setup your dns records correctly, or you have any they just haven't propagated yet.

koaning.com is still resolving to 91.184.0.95 which is not an amazon s3 ip address.

Double check steps #3 in the link you referenced above in the 'standard tutorial'.

Answer (score 0):

The dns parent servers return as hostnetbv.nl not as route53. As My Brennan noted, DNS is pointing to the wrong IP but I just wanted to make sure you have set-up your domain name to use Route53 name servers and not just configure the alias record without it.